# Pickle dumps and timestamps not matching what is expected

Tags: python, pickle, scapy

I'm manipulating scapy packets object with pickle in order to share them to different processes. 
However I'm witnessing that pickle changes the pkt.time attribute of my capture file :

- In order to reproduce this behaviour you just need a small pcap :

```
import pickle               
from scapy.all import *     # v2.4.3

def ppacket(pkt):
    print(pkt.time)           
    print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(pkt)).time) 

sniff(offline="test.pcap", prn=ppacket, count=10) #You only need one packet
```

Now running this on a pcap that was created earlier this month here's what I get :

```
1562587696.325424 #7/8/2019, 2:08:16 PM 
1567437619.227692 #9/2/2019, 5:20:19 PM
```

From what I understand the problem comes from the fact that this attribute is actually a defined as a function call :

```
#In scapy: packet.py 
def __init__(self, _pkt=b"", post_transform=None, _internal=0, _underlayer=None, **fields):  # noqa: E501
        self.time = time.time()
```

How can I avoid this behavior ? pickle was kind of great for me as I didn"t needed to care about formatting data before sending it to other processes.

Thank you for your help.

- pickle version :

```
$ pip freeze |grep pickle
jsonpickle==1.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
```

Edit 1 : 
After further digging I found that if I pickle only the time attribute it works as expected I don't understand how it is supposed to change anything.

```
print(pkt.time)    
    # > 1562587696.325424 #7/8/2019, 2:08:16 PM                    
print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(pkt.time))) 
    # > 1562587696.325424 #7/8/2019, 2:08:16 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to cope with this issue, since pickling only pkt.time works I just pickle the pkt and add pkt.time next to it :

```
dmp = pickle.dumps((pkt,pkt.time))
ld = pickle.loads(dmp)
print(ld[1]) #Works as expected.
```